# How can I use a different theme for checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I am having to work with a site that has quite a poor theme that really needs to be redone completely. I am not able to do that now but I do need to make the checkout and customer areas fully functional and visually appealing. The default **rwd theme** is a better starting point than the rubbish theme the site has.

Therefore, how can I change the layout of large parts of the site, e.g. the secure areas, to be a different design package/theme that only inherits from the built in themes?

If I could make just the checkout page work from the base themes/package that would be great.

Comment: What version of Magento?

Answer (score 1):

> In fact, the node in your `config.xml` file doesn't do an "update". As
>   a matter of fact, I think you have done that in your `config.xml` :
>
> ```
> <config>
>     <frontend>
>         <layout>
>              <updates>
>                   <checkout>
>                         <file>mylayout.xml</file>
>                   </checkout>
>              </updates>
>         </layout>
>     </frontend>
> </config>
> ```
>
> and you have done your modifications in `mylayout.xml`.
>
> In fact, you have to do :
>
> ```
> <config>
>     <frontend>
>         <layout>
>              <updates>
>                   <mymodule>
>                         <file>mylayout.xml</file>
>                   </mymodule>
>              </updates>
>         </layout>
>     </frontend>
> </config>
> ```
>
> And then, in mylayout.xml :
>
> ```
>        <reference name="content">
>             <reference name="checkout.cart">
>                 <block type="mymodule/myblock" name="checkout.mymodule.myblock"></block>
>             </reference>
>         </reference>
> </checkout_cart_index>
> ```
>
> By looking at my code and comparing the files to each other, you will
>   understand better how it works.
>
> In fact, don't forget that all xml files are concatenated in magento.
>   So that, all nodes in all config files, respecting the same order,
>   will be concataneted.
>
> For example, in our case, the `config.xml` files of magento will be
>   concatenated, and the result is ONE file containing :
>
> ```
> <config>
> <!-- some nodes... -->
> <!-- some nodes... -->
> <!-- some nodes... -->
>     <frontend>
>         <layout>
>              <updates>
>                   <mymodule>
>                         <file>mylayout.xml</file>
>                   </mymodule>
>                   <checkout> <!-- this is the node from the config.xml of the Checkout Module-->
>                         <file>checkout.xml</file>
>                   </checkout>
>                   <!-- some layout updates nodes from other config files... -->
>              </updates>
>         </layout>
>     </frontend>
> <!-- some nodes... -->
> <!-- some nodes... -->
> </config>
> ```
>
> If you had replaced `<mymodule>` by `<checkout>` the resulting file
>   would have looked :
>
> ```
> <config>
> <!-- some nodes... -->
> <!-- some nodes... -->
> <!-- some nodes... -->
>     <frontend>
>         <layout>
>              <updates>
>                   <checkout>
>                         <file>mylayout.xml</file>
>                   </checkout>
>                   <!-- some layout updates nodes from other config files... -->
>              </updates>
>         </layout>
>     </frontend>
> <!-- some nodes... -->
> <!-- some nodes... -->
> </config>
> ```
>
> Note the `mylayout.xml`. This is the reason why the original layout
>   file is completely replaced by your own layout :)
>
> Hope that's clear, in french it would have been easier for me to
>   explain ;)

Original Source:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2946191/158325